# Unix command line tool to find similar images

Tags: unix, images, duplicate

Is there some unix command line tool which can find similar images and output them as groups for further processing?

Comment: The definition of "similar" varies among people.  A few "mostly red" images are similar, images which contain my face are similar, images which differ only in being resized are similar, a small image which was cut out of a large image would be similar, an image which was converted from .png to .jpeg might be similar, etc.  It'd probably help to better define "similar". :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`findimagedupes`](http://www.jhnc.org/findimagedupes/) is a pretty creaky, old perl program, but you can still find it about and it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

Found [pHash](http://www.phash.org/) library. Though it is not a tool, its a library, but it is easy to integrate it and use.